# How To Get Concatenate Number Or String PHP With Long Consecutive Numbers In PHP?

Tags: php, loops, numbers, concatenation

So I want to get number with Consecutive Numbers like below.

1234567891011121314151617181920212223..............

when i input 10 then output is 1. and so on like below.

```
10th digit is 1
11th digit is 0
12th digit is 1
13th digit is 1
14th digit is 1
15th digit is 2
16th digit is 1
17th digit is 3
```

This is my code to make Consecutive Numbers. Its work as i want expected.

```
 <?php
          $i=1;
          $urut='';
          $a = $_GET['button1'];
          echo "Your number ", $a, "<br>";
          while ($i<=$a){
               $urut=$urut.''.$i;
               $i++;
          }

          $pecah = str_split($urut,1);
          echo "Urut angka ke ".$a."adalah ". $pecah[$a-1];
?>
```

But my case is how to get number when Consecutive up to 1 million or more.

I tried that but when set 1 millions or more its load very long time and cant show the result number

Comment: Don't use brute force

Comment: Is your question (as the title sais) about creating long loops and your code is just an example? Or is it about getting the nth digit when concatenating numbers? If the latter is the case (which I think), you should modify your title.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to do something like calculating the length of each range of numbers.
For example you know that:

- 1 through 9 are 1 character
- 10 through 99 are 2 characters
- 100 through 999 are 3 characters
- And so on

Doing so will allow you to calculate the length of the string up to a certain number.
For example the amount of characters before `1000` can be calculated like so.

```
9x1 + (99 - 10) x 2 + (999 - 100) x 3
```

Using this you can distil a formula which allows you to calculate the value for any given number.